# How do I download a vagrant image?

Tags: vagrant

I want to use `box-cutter/debian77` but when I try

```
vagrant box add box-cutter/debian77 https://atlas.hashicorp.com/box-cutter/debian77
```

I get

```
Downloading box from URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/box-cutter/debian77
Extracting box...e: 0/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

what is wrong? I have instlalled all archivers (unar, bsdtar, bzip2,...)

Or where can I download the image manually?

I use Vagrant 1.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.10. the same command works on a friend using arch and on debian wheezy too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a newer vagrant version.

I tried vagrant 1.6.5 and it works.

It seems 1.5 is required, see: https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant/issues/112#issuecomment-43425522

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're providing is that of a web page I think, not a tarball.  You just need to do this:

```
vagrant box add box-cutter/debian77
```

Comment: Then I get `This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
available below.

Usage: vagrant box add <name> <url> [--provider provider] [-h]`

Comment: Vagrant 1.7.1 didn't ask for the URL.  What version are you using?

Comment: vagrant 1.4.3 on ubuntu

Comment: [This](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/account-management/vagrant-1-7) seems to indicate 1.7 is a minimum requirement.

Have you tried:
`vagrant init box-cutter/debian77 ; vagrant up` or `vagrant box add box-cutter/debian77 https://atlas.hashicorp.com/box-cutter/boxes/debian77/versions/1.0.8/providers/virtualbox.box`?

Comment: Ok, I will try a newer version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569339/install-vagrant-version-1-5-or-greater-on-14-10